# Export Cells to Email based off range of dates using VBA

Tags: vba, email, excel, excel-2010

Hello Stackoverflow Community!

I'm completely new to VBA and I'm having some issues.

So I'm trying to export excel cells to an email within a specific date range. 
The program asks the user to enter the start date and the end date. The program then scans the excel sheet and pulls the data that either falls within the date range, or falls on the selected day(s). The data from the excel sheet is placed in a temporary workbook then from the temp work book - the data is then copied to an outlook email. The temp workbook is then deleted.

Please bear with me - being new to VBA my code is a little all over the place. I've been trying many solutions from the internet but they have not been working in my favor. The email opens up correctly with all the pre-filled HTML data (not included in the code below), but none of the data from the excel cells are there.  I know that my function RangeToHtml needs some re-working. Any tips to point me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub CommandButton4_Click()


   Dim newdate
   newdate = Date
   Dim rng As Range
   Set rng = Nothing
    Dim i As Integer
  newdate = Date - 6
   Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)


   If rng Is Nothing Then
   MsgBox " The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected." & _
    vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
 End If

    With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

   Set oLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set oMail = oLook.CreateItem(oMailItem)
   ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

   Dim strA As String, strB As String, strVerify As String



'Set Variable Values
strA = "You're about to send the weekely    OEM PPM Newsletter Update."
strB = "Are you sure you want to send the mail?"
strVerify = strA & vbNewLine & strB

   ' Set the optional introduction field thats adds
   ' some header text to the email body. It also sets
   ' the To and Subject lines. Finally the message
   ' is sent.
' Attaching the Header to the email'

    Const MyPath = "C:\Users\Jalexan1\Pictures\HEADER.jpg"
    Const MyPicture = "HEADER.jpg"

    With oMail
      .Subject = "WW OEM Weekly Update " & Date - 7 & " - " & Date
      .To = "some email@email.com"
      .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\Jalexan1\Pictures\HEADER.jpg"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng) & "<html>" & "<img src=cid:" & Replace(MyPicture, " ", "%20") & " height=200 width=980>" "</html>"



      '.Body = "WW OEM PPM WEEKELY UPDATE" & Date
    .Display


   End With

End If





Set oMail = Nothing
Set oLook = Nothing

End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    Dim rowcout As Long
    'rowcout = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row'
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rn As Range
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Set rn = sh.UsedRange
    LastRow = rn.Rows.Count + rn.Row - 1
    Dim startdate As Date, enddate As Date
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook
     Dim c As Range

     startdate = CDate(InputBox("Enter a Start Date in the format of MM/DD/YYY : "))
    enddate = CDate(InputBox("End Date: "))
    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'copy the range and create a new workbook to paste the data into'
     'LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
   For i = 2 To LastRow
    Dim cellcheck As Date
        datecheck = Range("A" & i).Value
        If datecheck >= startdate & datecheck <= enddate Then

        Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
        rng = Range(("A" & i)).Value
        MsgBox (rangerange)
        rng.Copy
            With TempWB.Sheets(1)
            .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
            .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
            .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
            Cells(1).Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            '.DrawingObjects.Visible = True
            '.DrawingObjects.Delete
           ' On Error GoTo 0
        End With
        End If
        Exit For
        Next i


    'Publish the sheet to a htm file

With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
        Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)

    End With

 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
 RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
 ts.Close
 RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsources=", _
                        "slign=left x:publishsource=")
    'close temp wb'
    TempWB.Close savechanges = False

    'Delete the temp file'
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: does it give you an error?

Comment: Yes, I get a run-time error '1004' Application defined or object-defined error   LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range(“A2” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  is the line causing the error

Comment: Try changing it to "A" & Rows.Count

Comment: When I changed it to "A" & Rows.Count, It threw another error: Run-Time error 13, Mismatch

Comment: Where is the new error happening?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are looking at cell "A2104856" which doesn't exist instead of cell "A1048576."  (Obviously this depends on which version of excel you are using, but either way, it is looking at a cell beyond the biggest possible row)

Try this:

```
 LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

and remove the "2" from "A2" & Rows.Count

The ampersand means to concatenate the string to the end of the previous one, not move down to the end of the column, so "A2" & "15" = "A215"

EDIT: This seems to have fixed the original problem, but there is another problem you have mentioned in the comments.

I noticed a misspelling in this line:

```
 RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsources=", _
                    "slign=left x:publishsource=")
```

"align" has been misspelled "slign".

UPdate this to:

```
 RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsources=", _
                    "align=left x:publishsource=")
```

However, as a general word of advice, if something is not giving you the output you desire (even if no errors are being thrown), the best first step is to step through the code and verify that each step in the code is doing what you want.

I don't know for sure that this is the only issue, and I'm not sure it would even create a blank email (it seems more likely to me that it would create one with strange formatting, but I haven't tested it), but if you step through this function, you will be able to see where it is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried changing LastRow as you suggested, but I still get the error - Run-time error '1004' - Application-defined or object defined error

Comment: Are you getting error 1004 or error 13 per the comment on the question?

Comment: Also, try declaring LastRow as Long, not Integer (this only matters if you have more than 32k rows, and it should throw an overflow, not one of these errors, but it can't help).

Comment: The error that I was getting was 1004. I solved that error it was due to something not being declared correctly.  LastRow now works correctly. Now I'm having an issue with selecting the specific cells and exporting them to outlook; The application doesn't throw an error, but the email doesn't contain any data from the cells.

Comment: I've found another issue and noted it in the answer.  However, as I state in the answer, I suggest stepping through the code to determine what is going wrong.  If you get stuck on a specific issue (can't get some function to work correctly), I'd be glad to help, but you need to try to do some troubleshooting yourself.